# Как определить, что iframe не загружен?

Tags: javascript, html

Как определить, что iframe не загружен, в том числе, если в него передан неправильный адрес? Или как определить, что он полностью загружен с корректным адресом и в нем есть содержимое?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. адрес: `window.frames['frame1'].window.location`. про неправильный адрес не совсем критерии "неправильности", возможно, придётся с чем-то сравнивать.
2. может, стоит попробовать `readyStatus`?(это про готовность фреймов, но тут я не уверен).
3. проверку содержит ли один из фреймов что либо можно попробовать так: `window.frames['frame1'].document.childNodes.lenght != 0`

И гугл всегда поможет [Выдача Google по запросу frame javascript](https://www.google.ru/#hl=ru&gs_nf=1&tok=9i8_GoU16iSCF5FCKV44ew&cp=5&gs_id=4f&xhr=t&q=frames+javascript&pf=p&newwindow=1&sclient=psy-ab&oq=frame&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=45ef85029423c78&biw=1787&bih=806)

Comment: спасибо.Буду решать.Делал через событие onerror ,но оно не помогает если адрес введен неправильно.